# Why JQuery UI sortable doesn't work in the if condition?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, jquery-ui, blazor

I want to create drag and drop funcionality with unordered list. So basically I check in the if condition if the list contains any items and if the list is not null, if I don't check then I get a error "Unhandled exception rendering component: Value cannot be null". I need so that there is no error but also to sort the list. So simply If I do this scenario below I can sort my list but I get error to the web console.

```
@if(myList.Any()) 
{     
      <ul id="sort">  
      @foreach(item in myList) {
          <li class="default">item.Property1</li>  
          <li class="default">item.Property2</li>  
          <li class="default">item.Property3</li> 
      }
      </ul>   
}
```

However, when I do this scenario I can't sort but error fixed:

```
@if((myList.Any()) && (myList != null)) 
{     
      <ul id="sort">  
      @foreach(item in myList) {
          <li class="default">item.Property1</li>  
          <li class="default">item.Property2</li>  
          <li class="default">item.Property3</li>  
      }
      </ul>   
}
```

also tried with initializing a new list like this but it doesn't work too:

```
private List<Something> myList = new List<Something>();
```

I don't understand why checking that the list is not null makes the drag and drop functionality not work... I am working in Blazor WebAssembly App with .net 7. Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Comment: Strange to have a hardcoded `ul` when you have a dynamic `myList`. Is there no iteration over that list to generate the HTML? Then what is the role of `myList` here?

Comment: In the second scenario, the condition `myList != null` should not change anything, because if the condition were not true (so `myList` would be `null`) the first condition would already have raised an exception. You cannot do `null.Any()`. Please make sure you provide code that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: Have you checked what the browser sees as HTML in both cases? What was the difference?

Comment: You probably want to change the if to `if (myList != null && myList.Any())` or `if (myList?.Any() == true)`

Comment: The above comments imply:  Razor `if` statements go left-to-right.   So the check for null needs to be before it is used (in the check for .Any) - ie on the left.